# Empty Directory Size

Tags: filesystems

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 xyz xyz 176128 Jul 29 02:03 20170429  
drwxrwxr-x 2 xyz xyz 110592 Jul 31 01:22 20170430

cd 20170429  
ls -lart  
total 196  
drwxrwxr-x   2 xyz xyz 176128 Jul 29 02:03 .  
drwxrwxr-x 253 xyz xyz 20480 Aug  4 00:00 ..  


du -sh 20170429
176K    20170429

du -sh 20170430
124K    20170430
```

Referring to the above information, I wanted to know for the empty directories `20170429`, `20170429` , why is it still showing having memory space of 176128 and 176128 while we do `ls -lrt`. Where from do these information comes from? Is it from inode? Also note that even by `du -sh` they still shows 176k and 124k respectively for the empty directory.

Comment: [this answering your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26666642/4023950)

Comment: [How directory size is calculated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356682/170373)

Comment: [What does size of a directory mean in output of 'ls -l' command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55/170373)

Comment: [\`du\` get different results on different machines for the same folder](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/74908)

Comment: [size of directory reported by ls](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/252238)

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that the directory has contained a large number of files in the past and the filesystem does not truncate the directory entry upon deleting files.

Example:

```
$ mkdir test_dir

$ du -h test_dir
2.0K    test_dir

$ touch test_dir/file{001..500}-{01..10}
```

We now have a directory with 5000 empty files in it.

```
$ du -h test_dir
102K    test_dir
```

The size comes solely from the directory entries of the empty files.

```
$ rm test_dir/file*

$ du -h test_dir
102K    test_dir
```

The size does not decrease (on this filesystem) as the files are deleted.

Comment: Did you do this on a local filesystem or NFS?  Your example #1 shouldn't work that way on a local filesystem like ext.  `du` won't find and add up the size of the deleted file.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Ah. I'm running on NFS. I will add that little bit of info to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @roaima It's apparent that I was wrong with that assumption, cutting answer down a bit.